# Ant build on InteliiJ Community Edition no compiler errors shown

Tags: ant, intellij-idea

I have an existing project that I want to build in the IntelliJ Community Edition 11.1.4 running on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS

In the Ant Build window I added the project's `build.xml` by clicking on the <kbd>+</kbd> button in the top left hand corner of the window and navigating to the file. The ant tasks associated with the build file are listed and I click on the green play button to run the ant build which commences as expected.

I was expecting to see compiler errors and have IntelliJ CE present those compiler errors and allow me to Jump to (the offending) Source having double clicked on the errors in the Messages window.

Instead, the messages window displays the following error which when I double-click on it takes me to the `javac` ant task in the `build.xml` file.

```
build.xml:389: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

This is great advice and I very much want to follow it but I cannot because the compiler error is not displayed anywhere in the **Messages** window. Next and Previous Message do not navigate to an actual compiler error.

I want to know how to be able to see the compiler error messages in IntelliJ having run an Ant build.

I tried adding the -v flag to the Ant command line:field in Execution Properties. This made no difference to the behaviour.

I then tried down grading from Ant 1.8 to Ant 1.7. this time I did see a change in behaviour. the build does not run at all and I get the following error https://gist.github.com/4073149 at the terminal.

The `javac` ant task looks like this.

```
<target name="compile-only" depends="">
    <stopwatch name="Compilation"/>
<javac destdir="${build.classes.dir}" debug="on" deprecation="off" 
       classpathref="base.path" excludes="/filtering/**/**">
    <src path="${src.dir}"/>
    <src path="${build.autogen.dir}"/>
</javac>
<!-- Copy all resource files to the output dir -->
<copy todir="${build.classes.dir}">
    <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
        <include name="**/*.properties"/>
        <include name="**/*.gif"/>
        <include name="**/*.png"/>
        <include name="**/*.jpg"/>
        <include name="**/*.svg"/>
        <include name="**/*.jpeg"/>
        <exclude name="**/.svn"/>
    </fileset>
</copy>
<stopwatch name="Compilation" action="total"/>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

IDEA just prints Ant's output. Try switching the output from the tree view to the plain text view using the corresponding button on the left of the messages panel:

[image: Plain Text View]

If the output contains errors, you should be able to see them there.

Also it's much faster and easier to use IDEA provided incremental compilation (`Build` | `Make`).

Comment: Switching from Tree View to plain text helped shed light on what was happening. Many thanks again for that tip. It made it clear that there is a crucial environment/configuration difference between running ant from within bash as opposed to IntelliJ. It's a complex build. Will post the final answer when I have figured it out if it is general enough. (Didn't get a chance today) It's highly unlikely to be a problem with IntelliJ, rather a possible ant 1.8 vs ant 1.7 issue or environment misconfiguration from within Idea. Thanks again, Rob

Comment: @RobKielty, did you ever find a solution to this?  I'm having a very similar problem and was curious as to what you did to solve it.

Comment: @Joshc1107 I honestly cannot recall and am away from my own PC right now to dig through the archive. I would say post your question. CrazyCoder will likely be able to shed light on what is going on for you and I will have a go at helping you out myself when I get home.

Answer (score 1):

When using plain (not tree) output  for ant IntelliJ uses 
`file (line,col): error msg` format for javac errors. 
But error view parser only understands `file:line: error msg` format.

You could tweak it in PlainTextView class from antIntegration.jar
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.jetbrains/intellij-idea/10.0/com/intellij/lang/ant/config/execution/PlainTextView.java#98

I just changed addJavacMessage method to following and recompiled the class
``` java

```
 public void addJavacMessage(AntMessage message, String url) {
    final VirtualFile file = message.getFile();
    if (message.getLine() > 0) {
      final StringBuilder builder = StringBuilderSpinAllocator.alloc();
      try {

        if (file != null) {
          ApplicationManager.getApplication().runReadAction(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
              String presentableUrl = file.getPresentableUrl();
              builder.append(presentableUrl);
//              builder.append(' ');
            }
          });
        }
        else if (url != null) {
          builder.append(url);
//          builder.append(' ');
        }
//        builder.append('(');
        builder.append(':');
        builder.append(message.getLine());
        builder.append(':');
        builder.append(' ');
//        builder.append(message.getColumn());
//        builder.append(")");
        print(builder.toString(), ProcessOutputTypes.STDOUT);
      }
      finally {
        StringBuilderSpinAllocator.dispose(builder);
      }
    }
    print(message.getText(), ProcessOutputTypes.STDOUT);
  }

  public void addException(AntMessage exception, boolean showFullTrace) {
    String text = exception.getText();
    showFullTrace = false;
    if (!showFullTrace) {
      int index = text.indexOf("\r\n");
      if (index != -1) {
        text = text.substring(0, index) + "\n";
      }
    }
    print(text, ProcessOutputTypes.STDOUT);
  }
```

```

And now I have clickable links in 'plain text' output mode of ant tool.
Note, that 'tree mode' shows line & columns correctly - I used IDEA 13 CE.

It would be nice if somebody to create pull request for Intellij regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ant Correct usage in IntelliJ:

```
javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${src.dir}" fork="yes" executable="D:/jdk1.7/bin/javac"
      destdir="${classes.dir}" includes="**/*.java" source="7" classpathref="library.classpath" ...
```

the most important:

```
executable="D:/jdk1.7/bin/javac"
```