# intelliJ - compiler error output not visible

Tags: ant, intellij-idea

I have gone crazy today while trying to understand where I can find *"compiler error output"* of below exception caused by my ant build script,

```
D:\Development Code\workspace\MVC\build.xml:131: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1150)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:912)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
```

Please help!

Regards
Rajib

Comment: Solved !! Problem was in my Junit jar file, it was not accessible by ant. I found it out after running the ant script in Eclipse.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I have the same problem.
Did you only solve the error leading to this problem, or did you find out where "compiler error output" is?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate issue of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383183/ant-build-on-inteliij-community-edition-no-compiler-errors-shown

Comment: @bluebaby, Sorry I did not find out where "compiler error output" is, however I have imported the project to eclipse and built; It showed the errors.